# Is there much additional overhead when retrieving an additional row from a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

I have two classes a master with a list of questions and detail with a list of answers. Each question can have one or many answers.

I have two choices and I would like to get some opinions on which one would be best:

1. Store the question data in a Question table.  Take the answers, create a JSON string 
   of these and add these to a field in the Question table. When the data is retrieved 
   from the table I could then convert the JSON string back into an object containing a 
   list of answers.
2. Store the question data in a Question table and the answer data in multiple rows in
   an Answers table.

with:

1. Everything could be retrieved with one database look up of the Question table
2. One database look up for the question data and multiple look ups for the answers

I am thinking that (1) would be faster and (2) would be easier to manage.

The second method (2) would require a retrieval of data from the Question table and then multiple retrieves of data from the answer table. With SQL server is it reasonable to assume about 10ms to get data from a table by primary key? How about taking data from the answer table and then from each additional row. I just have no idea how much time might be involved and would appreciate any advice that could be given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a SQL Join statement to retrieve Questions along with all corresponding answers.

```
Select * from Questions inner join Answers on Questions.ID = Answers.QuestionID
```

Just to give an example.

Comment: What I am worried about it the performance. Doing a job would require a multi-row access to the second table and I am not sure how much additional overhead that would require.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get why you would need to access each entry in the second tabel separately?
The join avoids this, editing or inserting an answer is also a single action. A join is basic sql, the engine is optimized for this task. Use an index if retrieval on key columns is expensive.

Comment: I guess what I am thinking is that if there are twelve answers then that would require an additional 12 disk accesses for each Answer table row.

Comment: No, that's not how a database is organized. Sure there will be IO but indexing correctly will avoid too much tablescans. Using a correct index will organize clusters on leaf level and that provides best performance. If your scenario is not that big, those type of selects won't affect performance significantly.